# PHP timer that resets after x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, datetime, timer

I trying to implement a timer to my website, as I want the timer to be the same for anyone entering, even if the timezones is different, I believe PHP works better than javascript, using **time()** maybe?

I'll explain.
I want my timer to start at 50 seconds and go to 0 seconds, once it hits 0 the timer should reset. So, as mentioned, when I reload the page the timer should not reset. If the timer is e.g **34**, and I reload the page, the timer should not reset back to **50**, it should keep going, so if it takes 2 seconds to reload the page, the timer should be **32** in this case.

The timer should also be the same of everyone, if my friend in Russia is seeing **44** seconds, then my friend in Spain should also see **44** seconds.

I don't have an example code as I simply don't know how to do it.

Comment: The time remaining should be coming from the web server so it shouldn't be affected with a page refresh. When setting the time remaining you may need to store it as a unix_timestamp value. This will allow JavaScript to pick up the value easily. On your web page you need to set up a JavaScript function to decrease the time remaining. You'll need to look at the setInterval function.

Comment: And that will work if I also want a php code to execute once the timer hits 0?

Comment: If you are wanting more than just a count down timer then you'll need to send both the original time and the time remaining to the browser. The browser will then need to handle the zero value by sapping zero for the original time.

Comment: I assume I should use node.js

Comment: Why? JavaScript will still have to handle the value when the timer reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the best, maybe even the worst method but it works.

```js
var count = 50;
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
  count--;
  if (count < 0){
  count = 50;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="counter"></h1>
```

Comment: That won't work, that will execute once. I want the timer to be visible.

Comment: No this wont work because once the page is delivered to the browser then the php connection is lost. The only way to include php in the mix is by using AJAX. In this instance AJAX is not necessary.